# Calculate $P(X^2-Y^2=3)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $(X,Y)$ be a continous random vector with density:

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\begin{cases}
   \frac{6}{7}(3y+x), & 0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1 \\
   0, & otherwise
\end{cases}$$

Calculate $P(X^2-Y^2=3)$

I'm not sure how to justify this, but since it's a continous random variable and is asking for an equality, should this be $0$?

Comment: @Sikking:  the requested probability is zero as the random vector is absolutely continuous

Comment: The integration of $f_{XY}$ over the unit square seems not to be 1?

Comment: @CharlieChang:  the joint domain is a triangle, not the unit square. $f(x,y)$ is a nice joint density, what is wrong is the probability request that should be $\leq$ or $\geq$